# Associate App with Messages Extension

Tags: ios-app-extension, ios10

I created a Messages Extension in Xcode 8 using the appropriate template, that seems to be working fine and when I run the extension, it's installed in the Messages app and I can use it without any issues.

My problem is that I wanted to create an actual app to be associated with this extension (so that the user would be able to search the extension through the Messages Store or install the actual app through the App Store). I gave it a matching bundle identifier (my extension is com.XXX.testmessage.MessagesExtension, so for the app I set com.XXX.testmessage), but when I run the app, it doesn't install the extension.

Is it possible to do that? And if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XCode8, open your existing app. Then you need to add a new target to your app (File->New->Target->iOS->Sticker Pack Extension (or an iMessage Extension if you want a custom messages experience)). It will then create a folder visible in Project Navigator. The name of the folder depends on the name you gave to the extension. In that folder you will find a Stickers.xcassets where you can drop your stickers.

Comment: What happens if users have your app, still have iOS9 and the new app version includes stickers? Is there a compatibility issue?

Comment: Also do you know if, upon user updates, the app will simply become available to them or what's required for that part?

Comment: If they are on iOS9 they just cannot use the stickers. As regards to your second question, I didn't understand it. When you said "user updates" you mean updates app, or updates to iOS10? If the latter, and the user already his the updated app, then the stickers should be available to them

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answers it. My confusion is on two things. First, with normal code if I add a feature that's not available on an older iOS, when a user with an older iOS runs my app, it'll cause an error unless I coded some safe unwrapping, etc. So the question was, will adding stickers cause problems for users still on earlier iOS's. Second, do I need to do any coding so the stickers show up or now that the extension is there, is it automatic?

Comment: For the stickers extension it seems to be automatic (since it's mostly drag and drop of images to get it the stickers extension done). So probably Apple is handling that stuff underneath the hood.